# Get field from mongoDB in an Array without updating data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, studio3t

How can I get a field in an array without updating DB collection? I need one field in an Array for a code in Node js. for example I have

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("abcs1234566"),
"name": "A"
},
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("sfdghjk234"),
"name": "B"
},
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("hgfd765"),
"name": "C"
}
```

What I need result is [A,B,C].

Answer (score 2):

You can use the javascript map function:

```js
const dbResult = [{ "_id" : "abcs1234566", "name": "A" }, { "_id" : "sfdghjk234", "name": "B" }, { "_id" : "hgfd765", "name": "C" }];

const names = dbResult.map(x => x.name);

console.log(names);
```